# Как на самом деле работает стек функции в С++?

Tags: c++

Уважаемые коллеги! Мне хочется понять как работает стек, на примере функции из трёх переменных.

```
 void f2() 
 {
        int B = 5;
        int *pB = &B; // задание адреса в указатель
        int &sB = B; //задание объекта в ссылку
        cout << "addres of  B = " << &B << "\n";
        cout << "value of  B = " << B << "\n";
        cout << "addres of  pB = " << &pB << "\n";
        cout << "value of  pB = " << pB << "\n";
        cout << "addres of  sB = " << &sB << "\n";
        cout << "value of  sB = " << sB << "\n";            
    }

    int main()
    {
        f2();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
addres of  B = 0038F644
value of  B = 5
addres of  pB = 0038F638
value of  pB = 0038F644
addres of  sB = 0038F644
value of  sB = 5
```

**1.** Непонятка между первой и третьей строкой. В адресном пространстве, как я полагал, адрес более новой переменной должен быть больше старой. На деле:

```
 `0038F638 - 0038F644 = -C;`
```

То есть сдвиг на 12 позиций назад. Хотя один из программеров с большим опытом, говорил, что сдвиг пойдёт на 4 позиции вперёд - на размерность `int`, который выражен в байтах.

**2.** Адрес `sB` - вообще совпал с адресом `B`! А значение `sB` - совпал сo значением `B`! Мне казалось очевидным, что значение помещенное в `sB` должно быть равным адресу `B`. А адрес `sB` должен быть сдвинут на четыре позиции (`sizeof(int)`) вперёд, относительно адреса предыдущей переменной.

**Вопросы:**

Чем можно объяснить наблюдаемое поведение? Каким образом (на самом деле) происходит присвоение адреса следующей переменной, относительно предыдущей? Есть ли возможность распечатать стек более грамотным способом, чем это я сделал? (Я хочу видеть стек в виде трой записей - **тип - значение - адрес**).

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут мог сработать оптимизатор. Для лучшего понимания можете сгенерировать код ассеблерный. Из данного кода может получиться совсем не такие машинные кода, которые вы ожидаете. Ещё могу порекомендовать прочитать "Современные операционные системы" о работе стека.

Comment: На это нельзя полагаться, это поведение на совести компилятора.

Comment: Что и как размещает в стеке компилятор - это его, компиляторово, дело. А еще есть разные архитектуры, разные ключи компиляции, разные оптимизации... А еще и стек обычно растет **вниз** (кстати, что в вашем примере и наблюдается).

Comment: Компилятор имеет право вообще вытеснить переменную из стека в регистр. (Особенно если вы не берёте её адрес.)

Comment: В общем случае все это верно, однако, понаблюдав за конкретным компилятором, всегда можно сделать некоторые выводы о его алгоритме размещения переменных в стеке. В частности, g++ сначала (в памяти с большими адресами) размещает массивы, затем переменные с большими требованиями к выравниванию (указатели, long long, double ...), а в конце short и char. Что же касается вывода, то можно набросать что-то вроде такого макроса `#define Info(v) std::cout << #v << "\thas type: " << typeid(v).name() << " value: [" << (v) << "] addr: " << (void *)&(v) << '\n'` (вызывать для каждой переменной)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> В адресном пространстве, как я полагал, адрес более новой переменной должен быть больше старой.

В большинстве "традиционных" платформ стек растет сверху-вниз: от старших адресов к младшим. Поэтому даже если бы компилятор размещал ваши переменные "по порядку", то не было бы ничего удивительного в том, что адрес более "новой" переменной меньше адреса более "старой".

Но на самом деле никакого порядка в размещении отдельных переменных нет и ваши сравнения адресов - бессмысленны.

В традиционной реализации память для всех локальных переменных функции выделяется сразу, одним "кадром стека" в начале работы функции. Внутри этого кадра стека компилятор еще на стадии компиляции разработает некую фиксированную карту расположения локальных переменных. При этом он может (и будет) располагать локальные переменные в этой карте совершенно произвольным образом, руководствуясь оптимизационными соображениями выравнивания, экономии памяти и т.д. и т.п. Поэтому **ваш порядок объявления переменных не значит вообще ничего** и разность адресов двух "соседних" переменных может быть какой угодно как по величине так и по знаку.

> Адрес sB - вообще совпал с адресом B!

Какой еще "адрес `sB`"? `sB` - ссылка. Ссылочный тип не является объектным, концептуально памяти не занимает и адреса не имеет. Никакого "адреса sB" в языке С++ нет и быть не может. После объявления `int &sB = B;` выражение `&sB` будет давать именно адрес `B`, что вы и наблюдаете. Нет ничего удивительного в том, что адрес `B` совпадает с адресом `B`.

> Каким образом (на самом деле) происходит присвоение адреса следующей переменной, относительно предыдущей?

Никаким конкретно. Как компилятору захочется в данном конкретном случае - так и будет. Эти решения принимаются компилятором на основе логики, которая на уровне языка не видна.

Какой-то порядок в языке С++ существует (может существовать) только между элементами одного массива или полями одного класса.

> Есть ли возможность распечатать стек более грамотным способом, чем это я сделал? (Я хочу видеть стек в виде трой записей - тип - значение - адрес).

На уровне языка - разумеется, нет.

А дальше можете поизучать формат отладочной информации, генерируемой вашим компилятором, и те API, которые ваша реализация предоставляет (если предоставляет) для доступа к этой отладочной информации. Там все это будет.

Comment: Некоторый порядок в размещении переменных для конкретного компилятора найти можно, но придумать, когда это можно использовать в практическом смысле трудно.

Answer (score 10):

Мы чуть-чуть посмотрим на то, как разместил переменные компилятор. Я воспользуюсь тем, что в исходном посте не сообщается каким компилятором пользуется автор, поэтому, как говорят математики, без потери общности, можно считать, что компилятор - gcc.

Сохраним код из исходного поста в файл `prnlocal.cpp`, добавив к нему

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

и закоментировав

```
/* system("PAUSE"); */
```

Многие разделяют мнение о том, что интеловский ассемблерный код удобнее читать, чем ассемблер AT&T, поэтому сгенерируем ассемблерный код командой

```
g++ -masm=intel -S prnlocal.cpp
```

Получим файл `prnlocal.s`, в котором найдём метку `_Z2f2v` - так C++ кодирует имя функции f2, имеющей параметр `(void)`.

```
         ....
_Z2f2v:
.LFB971:
        .cfi_startproc
        ......
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], 5 ; вот это - наша инициализация B=5
        lea     rax, [rbp-28]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rax ; вот это - инициализация pB = &B
        ....
```

Разберёмся с тем, что здесь написано, подробнее. В нашей архитектуре стек реализуется с помощью двух специализированных регистров: rbp и rsp. rbp указывает на основание стека, а rsp - на вершину стека.

Стек у нас растёт от больших адресов к меньшим, то есть в нормальных условиях `rbp > rsp`.

Первый интересный оператор:

```
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], 5
```

В расположенные по адресам `[rbp-28 ... rbp-25]` 4 байта нужно записать число 5. В результате число 5 попадёт в байт, расположенный по адресу `rbp-28`, а остальные три байта будут инициализированы нулями.

Следующая команда

```
    lea     rax, [rbp-28]
```

загрузит адрес `[rbp-28]` в регистр `rax`.

А третий оператор загрузит значение из регистра `rax` в восемь байт [rbp-40...rbp-33].

```
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rax
```

Интересно, что наша программа не использует байты по адресам [rbp-32...rbp-29]. Это результат размещения 64-битных переменных по адресам, кратным восьми - так называемого [*выравнивания данных*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) по адресам кратным 8.

В итоге у нас получился вот такой стек

```
        +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7
rbp-40  44 F6 38 00 00 00 00 00
rbp-32  ZZ ZZ ZZ ZZ 05 00 00 00  
rbp-24
rpb-16
rbp-08
```

Здесь по адресу `rbp-40` размещено значение переменной `pB`, а по адресу
`rbp-28` - значение переменной `B`.

О том, что размещено между `rbp-24` и `rbp`, тоже можно узнать из ассемблерного кода, но это отдельная история.